# Show that Foata map $\Phi$ implies there is a bijective map $co\Phi$ on $S_n$ such that $comaj(\sigma) = inv(co\phi(\sigma))$.

Tags: combinatorics

*Problem Statement:*

> If $\sigma$ is a permutation in $S_n$ define the co-major index of $\sigma$ as follows:
> $$\operatorname{comaj}(\sigma) = \sum_{\sigma_i > \sigma_{i+1}}(n-i).$$
> Show that Foata map $\Phi$ implies there is a bijective map $co\Phi$ on $S_n$ such that $comaj(\sigma) = \operatorname{inv}(co\Phi(\sigma))$. Refer to $\Phi$ and its properties.

*What I know*

> $\operatorname{maj}(\sigma) = \sum_{\sigma_i > \sigma_{i+1}} i = \operatorname{inv}(\Phi(\sigma) $

My thought was to rewrite the comaj in terms of the maj as follows:
$$\operatorname{comaj}(\sigma) = \sum_{\sigma_i > \sigma_{i+1}}(n-i) = n -\sum_{\sigma_i > \sigma_{i+1}}i$$

Then I realized that $n$ is probably not a constant and got stuck. I am not sure what the right approach to this problem is.

Comment: In the second equality of the last formula, $n$ repeats on the right as many times as there are summands on the left, i.e. $\operatorname{des}(\sigma)$ times. So, $$\operatorname{comaj}(\sigma)=\sum_{i\in\operatorname{Des}(\sigma)}(n-i)=n\operatorname{des}(\sigma)-\sum_{i\in\operatorname{Des}(\sigma)}i=n\operatorname{des}(\sigma)-\operatorname{maj}(\sigma).$$ Here, $\operatorname{Des}(\sigma)$ is the *descent set* of $\sigma$, and $\operatorname{des}(\sigma)=|\operatorname{Des}(\sigma)|$ is the number of descents of $\sigma$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the reversal of complement of $\sigma$, $\sigma^{rc}$, obtained by reading $\sigma$ right-to-left upside down (i.e. rotating its permutation diagram $180^\circ$). In other words, $\sigma^{rc}(i)=n+1-\sigma(n+1-i)$.

Then $i\in\operatorname{Des}(\sigma)$, i.e. $\sigma(i)>\sigma(i+1)$, is equivalent to
$$
\sigma^{rc}(n-i)=n+1-\sigma(i+1)>n+1-\sigma(i)=\sigma^{rc}(n-i+1),
$$
i.e. $n-i\in\operatorname{Des}(\sigma^{rc})$. Therefore, $\operatorname{comaj}(\sigma^{rc})=\operatorname{maj}(\sigma)$, and vice versa, $\operatorname{maj}(\sigma^{rc})=\operatorname{comaj}(\sigma)$.

Thus, $\operatorname{comaj}(\sigma)=\operatorname{maj}(\sigma^{rc})=\operatorname{inv}(\Phi(\sigma^{rc}))$.

So, we could define $\operatorname{co}\Phi=\Phi\circ(r\circ c)$, where $r$ and $c$ are the reversal and complement maps, $r(\pi)(i)=\pi(n+1-i)$, $c(\pi)(i)=n+1-\pi(i)$.